# Commands not working in Windows 7 32-bit command prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, 32-bit

I have an HP laptop with a Windows 7 32-bit Home Premium operating system. My command prompt doesn't run lots of commands like **help**, **shutdown**, **ipconfig**, **ping**, etc. I get a message like:

```
 'help' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Only simple commands like **cd** and **dir** are working. I noticed that whenever I navigate to `c:/windows/system32`, the command works. But I need to run some important commands like **java** on a file that is on the desktop and not in the system32 folder.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please type "echo %path%" and give the output. It seems that your PATH environment variable is corrupt (cd, dir, set are built into cmd.exe, programs like shutdown, ipconfig, ping are external programs and not builtin, therefor cmd.exe needs to have a good PATH variable to find the programs).

Comment: This might be a reason for not having `c:/windows/system32` folder in the path. Open command prompt. Enter `path` command. See whether it contains `c:\windows\system32` is in it or not. If not add it. You can use all the above mentioned commands.

Comment: @WernerHenze This is what i get `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\Syste
m32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C
:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;`

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi Is SystemRoot set correctly ("echo %SystemRoot%")?

Comment: There is a gap on the second line:`%SYSTEMROOT%\Syst‌​e m32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` between the Syste and the m. You maybe should fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that when you type `set path` in a command prompt the path also contains `PATH=%systemroot%\system32`. If this is the case your `%systemroot%` does not get expanded to `C:\Windows` (or other real Windows-directory) when starting `cmd.exe`.

You can check your registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`. All the names containing values with `%` characters (e.g. `windir`, `temp`, `path` and `comspec`) **should be** of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` (and **not** `REG_SZ`) or the variable won't be expanded.

You should also check `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` if `path` is of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.

Comment: Upvote because this is a very good point and it fixes the real cause.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the environment variables aren't set the right way:

1. Right click `Computer` → `Properties` → `Advanced System Settings` → `Advanced` (tab) → `Environment Variables…`
2. In `System variables`, double-click on `Path` (or single-click, and click on `Edit…`) to examine (and, if necessary, edit) the variable.
3. You have to make sure that these directories are defined in the Path variable:

   ```
   C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS
   ```

Comment: This is only true if windows is installed to C:\windows. The correct (out-of-the-box) setting is %SystemRoot%\system32.

Comment: Wow!!!. Thanks, I added the path to it and its now working perfectly

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi Glad I could help. You may accept the answer, so that other people can find the solution easier. :)

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi "%SystemRoot%\system32" is in your path, so please check %SystemRoot% - if it is wrong, then it should be set correctly and not a workaround with adding C:\windows\system32.

Comment: @WernerHenze Those were there before and were not wrong but the commands were still not working. I added what is in the answer and they are now working

Comment: What Werner means is, that you should do an `echo %SystemRoot%` to check, if the path is correct.

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi Please see Rik's answer, I am quite sure he has found the real cause (and there is no need to check `echo %SystemRoot%`).

Answer (score 1):

The path is now managed by Windows 7 and not the autoexec.bat or autoexec.nt files. To change the system environment variables, follow the below steps.

From the desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab.
In the Advanced section, click the Environment Variables button.
Finally, in the Environment Variables window (as shown below), highlight the Path variable in the Systems Variable section and click the Edit button. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you wish the computer to access. Each different directory is separated with a semicolon as shown below.

This is the default `PATH` environment variable setting on fresh install of Windows 7

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

Answer (score 0):

After editing the variable `PATH` a trillion times, I had to correct the variable `pathtext` to read `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC` instead of `COM;EXE;BAT;CMD;VBS;VBE;JS;JSE;WSF;WSH;MSC`. The difference the was the `.` (period) in front of the extensions. Wow!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is environmental variable ,Solve the problem as following steps
if path is not exist C:\Windows\System32 in environmental variable add in environmental variable   C:\Windows\System32 then reboot your machine.am sure you will get solution

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to above mentioned comment from DavidPostill and user470866!

I ran into the same problem and looking into the `PATH` variable checked if the default values are there! e.g.: `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

However, I noticed that the `PATH` variable was not starting with them but with some Java and Oracle references, hence I cut and copied the default one to the beginning of the line, e.g.: `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` in the beginning followed by all other stuff which was added by installed programs and saved and all of a sudden all my failing commands in CMD started working again.

Just an idea if anyone runs into this - apparently the **order of the values in the `PATH` variable matters**.

Thank you all for your guidance - it was extremely helpful!